# SQL Server sequence value getting decreased automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sequence

The below is the query for my sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE BATCH_NUM_SEQ 
    AS INTEGER
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 999999
    CYCLE
    CACHE 0
;
```

whenever I am trying to get the next value sometimes I could see the value getting decreased automatically. Sequence generated are given below

```
2345
2346
2347
2348
2311
2312
2313
```

Here sequence gets decreased after 2348 and started from 2311. What is the issue? Please help me to fix this. Thanks

Comment: How have you determined that the `2311` value was generated after the `2348` one?

Comment: Does ur sequence centralised. Means no other system is currently using ur SEQUENCE.

Comment: 2311 value generation after 2348 has been determined using the values stored in the database. 2348 generated and stored at 23rd January 2015 1.38 PM and 2311 generated and stored on the same day 2.15 PM.

Comment: Hi  Ankit Bajpai, My database server will be accessed by more than one application server at a time and those application servers will get the next sequence number may be at the same time also.

Comment: So are those times being generated on the database server or the application servers? If the application servers, are the server clocks synchronized and/or are they using the same timezone settings? It's far more likely that there's been a mis-diagnosis of the order in which rows were *actually* inserted than it is that the sequence suddenly jumps backwards.

Comment: Hi Damien_The_Unbeliever, My application servers are in different locations only, one is at Singapore and another one is at India. I am aware that there is time difference between these two servers and I got the generated values based on sorting my auto generated id. and I could able to see duplicate values for sequence numbers 2311 to 2348 in my database.